# Okuma OSP200M Switching screens by API

Tags: okuma

I am trying to add a feature to an Okuma application that can change the operating screens.
I have cycled through the enumerations and I believe the panelgroup I need is 0.

### I would like to be able to put the machine into "Manual Mode"

from what I have read in the API Options are Auto / MDI / Manual
Here is one of the variants that I have tried.

[image: Code Snippet]

It does not throw an error but it does not actually change the operating mode to manual.
If the machine is in Auto/MDI/Manual it will switch to that screen but not the mode.

Maybe I need to access some other API call or maybe I don't actually have API access to put the machine into a mode that code interrupt any other processing G-code..

Comment: So, I obviously had error message being suppressed. It does in fact throw an error.  E01030173002 Failed to change screen to panelgroup = 0 and screen name = Manual error code 20 abnormal panel group operation. maybe the word Manual doesnt need capitalized? So far I find the enumerations inside the API but no documentation of what string to pass for the name of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to change machining modes (Auto / MDI / Manual) is **not available** from the API.

> I can understand why someone may be confused about this point. The way things are worded in the API indicates that changing mode should be possible. That is because in the very early days of API, it was. At one time it was even possible to remote start a machine.

As you know, the Okuma API cannot cycle-start the machine due to safety concerns.
By the same token, changing machine modes while the machine is running in auto would stop / reset the machine. Therefore it is not allowed.